# Whats is the difference between mysql and sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Whats is the difference between mysql and sql ?
Please explain with code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question essentially asks for a basic explanation of `SQL`, of which there are **many** available on Google. StackOverflow expects you to [**research your problem**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) *before* asking for help. For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Comment: You're comparing Apple Juice to Apples. One is a product that uses the other; SQL is a language while MySQL is a database that uses SQL.

Comment: Search for `what is database`(mysql/oracle) and then search for `how to access data in database`(sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code won't be necessary I don't think.

SQL is the language used to manipulate data in a database.

MySQL is an enterprise data management system. It's one of a few different ways to manage your databases and utilize SQL to create, edit and delete those sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

**SQL vs MySQL**

**SQL** stands for **Structured Query Language**. It’s a standard language for accessing and manipulating databases. **MySQL** is a database management system, like **SQL Server, Oracle, Informix, Postgres**, etc. **MySQL is a RDMS** (Relational Database Management System).

**SQL Server and MySQL Vendors:**

The MySQL development project has made its source code available under the terms of the GNU General Public License, as well as under a variety of proprietary agreements. MySQL was owned and sponsored by a single for-profit firm, the Swedish company MySQL AB, now owned by Oracle Corporation.

SQL server is owned by Microsoft and is typically referred as Microsoft SQL Server. It has a long history of releases and it is updated often adding all latest trends and technologies to it thus making it one of the trusted data base applications today. At the 2011 PASS summit on October 11, Microsoft announced that the next major version of SQL Server, codenamed Denali, would be SQL Server 2012. The release date is set to the first half of 2012.

for more information please look link bellow

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/difference-sql-mysql